# Unable to set navigation bar background color - Android

Tags: android, android-navigation-bar

Inside an activity I need to have fullscreen, but when the user taps to show the navigation bar the background color of the bar is always black.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setSystemWindowFullScreen(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        setFitsSystemWindows(this,rootView); 
    }

    public void setSystemWindowFullScreen(Activity activity)
    {
        activity.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        activity.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

    int mUIFlag = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN;
    activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(mUIFlag);
}

public void setFitsSystemWindows(Activity activity,View rootView)
{
    //Set Navigation bar style 
    activity.getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(rootView, (v, insets) -> {
        ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams()).topMargin =
                insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop();
        return insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets();

    }); 
}

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item> 
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
</style>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in styles.xml :

```
            <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/theme_color</item>
```

or

```
          window.setNavigationBarColor(@ColorInt int color)
```

Comment: I need to do it programmatically